# How to create a RethinkDB data initialization script

Tags: database, rethinkdb

I'm trying to create a simple script that I can paste into the RethinkDB data explorer to initialize a database.

I can insert records fine with something like this:

```
r.db('testdb').table('cars').insert([{ "model" : Honda }])
```

But how can that be followed by a second insert into a related table like:

```
r.db('testdb').table('engines').insert([{ "cars_id" : <what goes here> }])
```

I could imagine writing some javascript to extract the newly created id's, but it doesn't appear that the data explorer supports things like variables.

Ideally there would be a way to write a large script that would work directly in data explorer for when needed for convenience.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data explorer can take multiple queries separated by a semi colon.
Note that queries will be sequentially executed, and only the result for the last query will be returned.

The data explorer supports some javascript to some extent, the requirements (as far as I know) are:

- the last query must be a ReQL query
- Any instructions must ends with a semi colon (except the last one)

That being said, you cannot use the result of the first query in the second query using JavaScript (you don't get access to the result). You can however nest queries (or chain with `do`), something like this should work I think:

```
r.db('testdb').table('cars').insert([{ "model" : Honda }]).do(function(result) {
  r.db('testdb').table('engines').insert([{ "cars_id" : <you can use the result of the insert here> }])
})
```